# Interpreters for the Free Monad

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads, scala-cats, free-monad

I've been doing an exercise to try to implement a basic Calculator with Free Monad.
As I understand the intention of the Free Monad and what I wanted to achieve is:
write my program (math expression) once run it with different interpreters.
Now i am not sure that I did the 100% idiomatic implementation at least because:

My program kinda needs to be parametrized on the generic type A which should match the interpreter context.

```
def program[A] = for {
      two <- lit[A](2)
      four <- lit[A](4)
      sum <- add(two, four)
    } yield sum

program[Int].foldMap(eval) shouldBe 6
program[String].foldMap(print) shouldBe "(2 + 4)"

import cats.instances.option._
program[Option[Int]].foldMap(evalOpt) shouldBe Option(6)
```

The ADT/algebra and 'smart constructors'

```
trait Expression2[A] extends Product with Serializable
  case class Lit[A](a: Int) extends Expression2[A]
  case class Add[A](a: A, b: A) extends Expression2[A]
  case class Mult[A](a: A, b: A) extends Expression2[A]

  type ExprAlg[B] = Free[Expression2, B]

  def lit[A](a: Int): ExprAlg[A] = Free.liftF(Lit(a))
  def add[A](a: A, b: A): ExprAlg[A] = Free.liftF(Add(a, b))
  def mult[A](a: A, b: A): ExprAlg[A] = Free.liftF(Mult(a, b))
```

The math interpreter:

```
def eval: Expression2 ~> Id = new (Expression2 ~> Id) {
    override def apply[A](fa: Expression2[A]): Id[A] = eval(fa).asInstanceOf[A]

    def eval[A](expression2: Expression2[A]): Int = expression2 match {
      case Lit(n) => n
      case Add(a, b) => a.asInstanceOf[Int] + b.asInstanceOf[Int]
      case Mult(a, b) => a.asInstanceOf[Int] * b.asInstanceOf[Int]
    }
  }
```

The print interpreter:

```
def print: Expression2 ~> Id = new (Expression2 ~> Id) {
      override def apply[A](fa: Expression2[A]): Id[A] = eval(fa).asInstanceOf[A]

      def eval[A](expression2: Expression2[A]): String = expression2 match {
        case Lit(n) => n.toString
        case Add(a, b) => "(" + a.toString + " + " + b.toString + ")"
        case Mult(a, b) => "(" + a.toString + " * " + b.toString + ")"
      }
    }
```

The math in Option interpreter:

```
def evalOpt: Expression2 ~> Option = new (Expression2 ~> Option) {
    override def apply[A](fa: Expression2[A]): Option[A] = eval(fa).map{_.asInstanceOf[A]}

    def eval[A](expression2: Expression2[A]): Option[Int] = expression2 match {
      case Lit(n) => Option(n)
      case Add(a, b) => Option(a.asInstanceOf[Int] + b.asInstanceOf[Int])
      case Mult(a, b) => Option(a.asInstanceOf[Int] * b.asInstanceOf[Int])
    }
  }
```

Related to the Option interpreter, I would have expected that the a and b vars to be option, and in the string interpreter a and b to be strings because of my the ADT result type is A: Expression2[A].

I also tried instead of Lit[A](a: Int), to have Lit[A](a: A) but then it breaks down: i cannot pass different interpreters for the same expression when A is fixed to an Int in my program and I expect not to have to rewrite my program for different interpreters.

Answer (score 2):

So a couple things. Generally you reaaaally want to avoid `asInstanceOf` because right now you can construct an `Expression2` with any type and then it'd just crash on evaluating because it's not actually an `Int`. There's a couple ways to mitigate this. You can either just fix the type of the contained numeric type in your `Expression2`

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._


trait Expression2[A] extends Product with Serializable
case class Lit[A](a: Int) extends Expression2[Int]
case class Add[A](a: Int, b: Int) extends Expression2[Int]
case class Mult[A](a: Int, b: Int) extends Expression2[Int]

type ExprAlg[A] = Free[Expression2, A]

def lit(a: Int): ExprAlg[Int] = Free.liftF(Lit(a))
def add(a: Int, b: Int): ExprAlg[Int] = Free.liftF(Add(a, b))
def mult(a: Int, b: Int): ExprAlg[Int] = Free.liftF(Mult(a, b))

val eval: Expression2 ~> Id = new (Expression2 ~> Id) {
    override def apply[A](fa: Expression2[A]): Id[A] = eval(fa)

    def eval[A](expression2: Expression2[A]): A = expression2 match {
      case Lit(n) => n
      case Add(a, b) => a+b
      case Mult(a, b) => a*b
    }
  }
```

Or you can associate the capability with the operations like this. basically you can think of the cases in your ADT like `Add` like this: The parameters of the case class are like function parameters and the type you put into the Extends is the result type.

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
import spire.algebra._
import spire.implicits._ 


trait Expression2[A] extends Product with Serializable
case class Lit[A](a: A) extends Expression2[A]
case class Add[A](a: A, b: A)(implicit val ev:Semiring[A]) extends Expression2[A]
case class Mult[A](a: A, b: A)(implicit val ev:Semiring[A]) extends Expression2[A]

type ExprAlg[A] = Free[Expression2, A]

def lit[A](a: A): ExprAlg[A] = Free.liftF(Lit(a))
def add[A](a: A, b: A)(implicit ev:Semiring[A]): ExprAlg[A] = Free.liftF(Add(a, b))
def mult[A](a: A, b: A)(implicit ev:Semiring[A]): ExprAlg[A] = Free.liftF(Mult(a, b))


val eval: Expression2 ~> Id = new (Expression2 ~> Id) {
  override def apply[A](fa: Expression2[A]): Id[A] = eval(fa)

  def eval[A](expression2: Expression2[A]): Id[A] = expression2 match {
    case Lit(n) =>  n
    case x:Add[A] => x.ev.plus(x.a,x.b)
    case x:Mult[A] => x.ev.times(x.a,x.b)
  }
}  

def program[A: Semiring](a:A,b:A) = for {
      two <- lit(a)
      four <- lit(b)
      sum <- add(two, four)
    } yield sum

println(program[Int](2,4).foldMap(eval) )
```

Now as for your Option case I am not quite sure why you want to interpret into an Option here. if you can do `F ~> Id` for some `F`, `F ~> Option` really is just `Some` applied to the first natural transformation.

Comment: The purpose is that wherever I read about FreeMonad it said that you can interpret the program with different interpreters, this is just a toy example, theoretically you could use Future to do parallel evaluations

Comment: The real test that I see for the correct solution would be to easily implement an interpreter to evaluate the expression and one to print it. With the fixed type in the ADT / Expression you can't do the string interpreter. Second solution looks doable, but the part which is strange is passing the interpretation for plus from outside, it is not left strictly to the interpreter.

Comment: @Blitzkr1eg The interpreter can't introspect on types (okay it _can_, but shouldn't), so how else are you going to constrain what can and can't be added?

Comment: (In my view this is just not a very good use case for `Free` unless you intend to compose `Expression2` with more interesting algebras (and even then it's a stretch).)

Comment: it really isn't the monad constraint of `foldMap` kinda gets into the way if you want to e.g. interpret it into `Reader[Semiring[X], X]` turns out easist is probably to just define a `FreeRig` much like `List` turns out to be the free monoid. it was a pretty cool exercise to work through